# Java parse .txt file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to run the below file TemplateMaker.java in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 and am running into the following error message. Netbeans shows no red indicators for me to fix. Please help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at templatemaker.TemplateMaker.processLine(TemplateMaker.java:48)
    at templatemaker.TemplateMaker.processLineByLine(TemplateMaker.java:35)
    at templatemaker.TemplateMaker.main(TemplateMaker.java:17)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is my source code:

```
package templatemaker;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TemplateMaker {

        public static void main(String [] args)
 throws IOException {
    TemplateMaker parser = new TemplateMaker("Book1.txt");
    parser.processLineByLine();
    log("Done.");
  }

  /**
   Constructor.
   @param aFileName full name of an existing, readable file.
  */
  public TemplateMaker(String aFileName){
    fFilePath = Paths.get(aFileName);
  }


  /** Template method that calls {@link #processLine(String)}.
     * @throws java.io.IOException */
  public final void processLineByLine() throws IOException {
    try (Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(fFilePath, ENCODING.name())){
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        processLine(scanner.nextLine());
      }      
    }
  }


  protected void processLine(String aLine){
    //use a second Scanner to parse the content of each line 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(aLine);
    scanner.useDelimiter("=");
    if (scanner.hasNext()){
      //assumes the line has a certain structure
      String name = scanner.next();
      String value = scanner.next();
      log("Name is : " + quote(name.trim()) + ", and Value is : " + quote(value.trim()));
    }
    else {
      log("Empty or invalid line. Unable to process.");
    }
  }

  // PRIVATE 
  private final Path fFilePath;
  private final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;  

  private static void log(Object aObject){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(aObject));
  }

  private String quote(String aText){
    String QUOTE = "'";
    return QUOTE + aText + QUOTE;
  }
}
```

Comment: You check with `hasNext()` once, and then read twice. Not a good idea.

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger and step through the code?

Comment: Not even a debugger needed. Normal console output would be enough ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `processLine()` is expecting a "name=value" pair. And as MightyPork said you are checking hasNext() once, and then read twice. So if that line does not have an `=` symbol this will break as scanner wont get the `next()` token. You should add two `hasNext()` checks. Ideally you dont need a scanner here. Since you are always expecting two tokens delimited by `=` you can simply rely on `java.util.StringTokenizer` as

```
protected void processLine(String aLine){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(aLine, "=");
    if(st.countTokens() == 2) {
        log("Name is : " + quote(st.nextToken().trim()) + ", and Value is : " + quote(st.nextToken().trim()));
    } else {
        log("Empty or invalid line. Unable to process.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the stacktrace indicates, the exception was thrown when scanner.next() was called

```
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)

if (scanner.hasNext()){
      //assumes the line has a certain structure
      String name = scanner.next(); // checked by hasNext()
      String value = scanner.next(); // not checked by hasNext()
      log("Name is : " + quote(name.trim()) + ", and Value is : " + quote(value.trim()));
}
```

The error must be in the second .next(). You check if the scanner has a next token, but you call .next() twice. So I assume there is 1 token left and you read twice. Also from the API the next() method:

```
Throws:
    NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available
    IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

You can check that easily by adding a System.out.println statement and check what's the last one before the exception (after the first or second call of next())